# How to set color of text letters individually?

Tags: java, android, andengine

How would I make text so that each letter is a random color in andengine GLES 2? For the random color I could go

```
int red = (int) (Math.random() * 254) + 1;
int green = (int) (Math.random() * 254) + 1;
int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 254) + 1;
Color pColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
```

but how can I set this to each letter individually?

Comment: For each color component, the accepted (float) value range is [0, 1], instead of (int) [0, 255].

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's with the downvotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

each letter would have to be it's own `Text` and set each one's color randomly - just do it

and when you create the `Text`, set the color to white on creation, then change it to your random color

BTW, there is no way (that I am aware of) to do it in a single `Text`