# Format text with tags in AndEngine

Tags: android, text, format, andengine

AndEngine.
Is it possible to display the text of the edited tags html or others.
Such as the color of some words in the text.

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible using just the andengine text class. A text object can only be one color. To make multi-color text you would need a new text object for each colored word.

See this post about coloring individual letters in a text field:

[How to set color of text letters individually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149881/how-to-set-color-of-text-letters-individually)